# woocommerce shortcodes filter to exclude category?

Tags: woocommerce, categories

Is it possible to use shortcodes, best seller for example, but filter to exclude a category?

I understand how to use [best_selling_products per_page="12"] or [product_attribute attribute='color' filter='black']

but I need to filter out my free stuff section so that doesn't show on best sellers.

Update:  I found exclude_categories="" but now I'm not sure what the category ID is. Is it the slug or name?

Answer (score 3):

In the latest version of Woocommerce, it provides a filter **woocommerce_shortcode_products_query** which you can use to exclude a category from that page

You can use the below  code in your theme's **functions.php** file to make it work.

But I would advice to do it using a [Child Theme](http://www.sourcexpress.com/wordpress-child-themes-use/)

```
function se_customize_product_shortcode( $args, $atts ) {
    if ( is_page( 'products' ) ) {
        $args['tax_query'] = array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => array( 'clothing', 'music' ),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
       );
    }

    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'se_customize_product_shortcode', 10, 2 );
```

You can use your respective is_page condition. For more details check out this blog [Exclude a category from the woocommerce product shortcode](http://www.sourcexpress.com/exclude-category-woocommerce-product-shortcode/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this shortcode `[recent_products category="category_link" operator="NOT IN"]`